# What is the difference between GNADIRS and ADIRS on the A320 family?

Tags: airbus-a320, inertial-nav-system

What is the difference between GNADIRS and ADIRS on the overhead panel of the A320 family?

Comment: I would guess with or without GPS..  Perhaps this might help? (https://www.smartcockpit.com/docs/A320-Navigation.pdf)